# Variance of Truncated Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim {N}(\mu,1)$ and let $Y$ denote its truncation for the interval $[0,1]$. What is the relationship between $Var Y$ and $\mu$? Is it monotone? I found that the relationship between $\mathbb{E}Y$ and $\mu$ is increasing with $\frac{\partial \mathbb{E}Y}{\partial \mu}=\frac{Var Y}{Var X}$ and would like to know about $\frac{\partial Var Y}{\partial \mu}$. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use your intuition.  The truncated distribution $Y$ will be symmetric when $\mu = 1/2$.  As you move $\mu$ away from $1/2$, intuition suggests the variance will not remain constant; therefore, it cannot be monotone--$\mu = 1/2$ must be a global extremum.

The question of whether it is a minimum or maximum will require additional thought.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am thinking out loud, but $\mu=1/2$ is the "point of maximum entropy" in the sense that the mass is evenly distributed above and below the mean. If $\mu>1/2$ then I am shifting more mass of the distribution towards large values, and the small deviations from the mean have more weight in the variance, then the variance must decrease. A similar argument can be made for $\mu<1/2$. Does that sound right?

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera Yes, that's very good intuition, and it is ultimately correct.  Of course, a formal proof would involve a lot of computation.

Comment: I managed to get a formal proof, will type it later. Thank you so much!